# How to upgrade virtuemart for joomla 1.5.26

Tags: joomla, upgrade, virtuemart

I have virtuemart version 1.1.7 was running on joomla 1.5.23.
Now I have upgraded to joomla 1.5.26, I need to upgrade virtuemart from 1.1.7 to 2.0.12 which is stable compatible one for joomla 1.5.x.
Any help on how to do this, I can't afford to install new version as all my user data will be lost in fresh installation of new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update VM version less than  2.0 to version 2.x.

Bcoz the VM changed the whole architecture of VM 2 (They implemented the MVC).
So you cannot upgrade directly,you need to install new VM 2.x and implement your older one changes one by one.Before doing any updation you should keep backup.

Comment: That's what developers get for not following MVC lol. However the older version of Kunena wasn't MVC based yet their upgrade went smoothly. Never the less, thanks for the info. +1

Comment: Thanks Jobin, I did the same, had to do a lot of work but it was worth an effort.

Answer (score 1):

I Had found some easy guide

Open your ftp client and go to “server —> administrator —> components” and change “com_virtuemart” to something else, i changed it to “old_com_virtuemart” (you may also do this for “server —> components”

1. move your product/manufacturer/vendor images into images/stories/virtuemart and there in the right sub-folders. (category, manufacturer, product, vendor)
2. disable all virtue mart extensions
3. set your default Joomla frontend language to the one used in the description of your products. It is important to do this step before updating Virtue Mart for installing the correct default Virtue Mart languages tables.
4. now go to your site and go to the installer
5. install virtue mart 2.0 (as said before, don’t install 2.1/2.0.1/2.2 etc.)
6. after the installer is done, install the sample data
7. after the sample data is installed go back to the installer and install the AIO component
8. go to the administrator, set the language(s) for your store, even if your store is not multilingual and save the Virtue Mart configuration.
9. now go to the configuration of in virtue mart and enable “Enable database Update tools”.
10. after that is done, go to Tools —> tools&migration —> and click on the tab migration
11. first choosehcoose ”Everything” and then click “Start Migration”
12. just click “Start Migration” as many times as it takes for all products to migrate
13. now install jupgrade (http://redcomponent.com/free-downloads/cat_view/931-jupgrade)
14. after installing is done go to the component jupgrade and click on preferences
15. make sure “Distribution” is set to Joomla 2.5 and make sure everything is set to “no” except “Keep original positions?” and “Delete previous migration” and save
16. now click on the big button to upgrade
17. after the upgrade is done go to www.your-site.com/jupgrade and log-in 
    (if the components are not upgraded don’t worry, you just have to install them again, but it may take some time…)
    if Virtue mart is still on your upgraded site, then you don’t have to follow the steps, go to step 27
18. install virtue mart 2.0 again and then install the sample data
19. install the AIO component
20. Now go to the administrator, set the language(s) for your store, even if your store is not multilingual and save the Virtue Mart configuration.
21. now go to the configuration of in virtuemart and enable “Enable database Update tools”.
22. after that is done, go to Tools —> tools&migration —> and click on the tab migration
23. first choose “Everything” and then click “Start Migration”

No matter which way of VirtueMart upgrading you will choose, don't forget to make a backup of your store data. So in case of any mistake ( it sometimes happen) you will be able to renew your store.

Comment: I followed these steps and everything worked. but I lost my product images. Not the jpg's but the reference between virtuemart products and the corresponding jpg.